# Python stomp client can not receive any message from Spring 2.x Stomp Service

Tags: spring, websocket, stomp

My spring 1.5 based stomp websocket server and python based stomp client was working fine.

After upgrading spring version to 2.x, the client no longer receives any messages. I have consulted the spring guide but can't find anything wrong.

Python based stomp client:

```
import stomper
from websocket import create_connection

ws = create_connection('ws://localhost:8080/ws')
ws.send(stomper.subscribe('/msg', 0))
print(ws.recv())
```

Spring 1.5 based stomp server:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
class DemoConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/msg");
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("ws");
    }
}

@Component
@EnableScheduling
class MessageBroker {
    @Autowired
    private SimpMessagingTemplate messenger;

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000)
    private void msg() {
        messenger.convertAndSend("/msg", "hello");
    }
}
```

Spring 2.x based stomp server(Implement an interface without extending the abstract class):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
class DemoConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/msg");
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("ws");
    }
}

@Component
@EnableScheduling
class MessageBroker {
    @Autowired
    private SimpMessagingTemplate messenger;

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000)
    private void msg() {
        messenger.convertAndSend("/msg", "hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get any connection messages when using debug logging?

Comment: The connection seems to be working well. It also works well for sending messages from client to server. When the server sends a message, however, the Python client subscribing to the destination receives no message.

Comment: did you find a solution for that ?